# Informal colloquial English: Can I remove are in "You still here?" or similar sentences?

Tags: informal-language

Suppose that you see a person who used to work with you in the same building but they left that job for another a year ago. You see them again in the same building and turn and say:

> Awo, you still in [The building's name]!!!

**Added later:** The building name would imply a sense of affiliation with that building. For example, suppose that sentence can be understood as "Are you working here again?"

Also, suppose you say this with a rising tone of voice as if you are really surprised to see them there. Is that a common thing to remove the be? I mean in the informal spoken American English?

---

S.N: I know in AmE, there are senetnces like "how you doing" or "where{'re?!} you going". Hence, I asked this question. I have a feeling that I've heard the similar structures many times before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "You still here?" is very common in colloquial speech.

"You still in?" I would understand as using the adverb "in" (usually meaning "at home"), not the preposition "in". To mean "Are you still in the building?" I would expect "You still inside?"

**Edit**: I misread part of the question. Yes, "You still in [name of building]?" is fine. I thought you were talking about "You still in?"

Comment: Thanks Colin, lets say the building's name is ELL and being in ELL implies a sense of affiliation with a specific organization. Then, I say, "You still in ELL?" as if I want them to answer me something like "No I no longer work here, just came to see someone"

Comment: @Cardinal: See my edit.

Comment: @Cardinal: I think in colloquial American, you might be more likely to say "Are you still at [company or firm name]?" which asks the precise question about their employment. (Or "Are you back at [firm name]?"). The version with the building is grammatical but sounds to my ears like a non-American colloquialism.